# Bose-Einstein condensate and one-particle state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate

I am a little confused about the definition of a Bose-Einstein condensate. It is said that, in such a condensate, a huge number of particles are in the same state of lower energy. The term *state of lower energy* is what bothers me. I understand it is *not* the collective energy of all particles but, rather, the ground state of the one-particle states, is that right?

More concretely, suppose I have a system of $N \gg 1$ identical particles, and the system is described collectively by the Hamiltonian:
$$H_{N} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}h_{i}$$
where the $h_{i}$ is the one-particle Hamiltonian of the $i$-th particle (I am indexing it by $i$ but these are all copies of the same one-particle Hamiltonian $h$). If $\varphi_{0}$ is the (assumed unique) ground state of $h$, then the system undergoes a phase transition to a Bose-Einstein condensate if a huge number of particles is in the state $\varphi_{0}$. It does *not* mean that the Bose-Einstein condensate is a ground state of $H_{N}$, but rather that most of its particles are in the ground state of $h$. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, for non-interacting particles, the ground state of $H$ is just $\varphi_0^{\otimes N}$... Ańyway, BEC is defined in terms of the so-called one-body reduced density matrix aka one-particle density matrix or similar. See e.g. Penrose and Onsager, 1956.